# start multiple kafka node on localhost (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to start a docker kafka and scale it on my localhost. Here is my initial docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

This works perfectly when I request with BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG="PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092".

Obviously, if I use docker-compose scale kafka=3 I will get an error because the port 9092 on the localhost is already used.

According to the doc : https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity , I tried to change the port like this :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

With this, if I request with BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG="PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092" my producer cannot send message because of a timeout. That mean the entry point is not KAFKA_LISTENERS or KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

If I use the port my docker has been binded (32001) : BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG="PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:32001" I got a different error message when trying to send a message :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for demo-0:120001 ms has passed since batch creation
```

I suppose there is something weird about KAFKA_LISTENERS and KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS but I can't find a way to make it work.

In my last tried I did :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 # or PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092 # or PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9093 
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

But that did not get anything right. 
If somebody have an idea, let me know.

Comment: You need to define more clearly what you mean by "I cannot get anything working". Do you get an error message? If so what? Log files? etc.

Comment: My Producer just cannot connect to kafka when trying to send his message (got a timeout). I'll run it again so I can write the exact logs.